# Нужна ли запятая после "года"?

Tags: пунктуация

Прошло два года как мы стали жить в отдельной квартире.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Нужна ли запятая после “два года”?

Предложение сложноподчинённое, разделительная запятая между его частями нужна:

***Прошло два года***, как **мы стали жить** в отдельной квартире.